# Cant to run copy of service with volumes using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-volume

I have docker-compose with volume:

```
volumes:

  code:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: 'none'
      o: 'bind'
      device: $PWD

services: 
  # .. Some services
```

I run it using gitlab-runner. Service works perfectly.

But now I need to run copy of service on same server.

I has created separate gitlab runner for it. And when I try to deploy copy of service I have next error:

> 18 $ docker-compose up -d --build
>   19 Configuration for volume code specifies "device" driver_opt /home/gitlab-runner/builds/MevxfSHX/0/semast/sa-parser, but a volume with the same name uses a different "device" driver_opt (/home/gitlab-runner/builds/BWs7_SoK/0/semast/sa-parser). If you wish to use the new configuration, please remove the existing volume "sa-parser_code" first:
>   20 $ docker volume rm sa-parser_code
>   24 ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1

Seems what it is collision in volume names. What I need to do to run copy of service?

Comment: Can you delete the volume declaration and just run the code that's baked into the image?  That's generally better practice anyways; one of the reasons to run Docker is that images are self-contained and you don't need to separately copy the runtime and the application code.

Comment: I use this volume for sharing code between php and nginx containers, so i cant delete it. And I dont use anonymous volumes in services (like `.:/var/www/html`) because it leads to another problem of "sticking" volumes in process of deploy. May be it is exists any way to deploy these volumes in different namespaces?

Answer (score 0):

I has modified `.gitlab-ci.yml`, to project now builds in another path, so volumes have another prefix.